# How do I limit a for-loop in GLSL with a Vec3 as iterator?

Tags: for-loop, vector, iterator, glsl

```
vec3 Origin = vec3(0,0,0);
vec3 StepValue = vec3(0,1,0);
vec3 Destination = Origin + (10*StepValue);

for (vec3 Stepper; Stepper==Destination; Stepper += StepValue)
```

This is not my actual code, but an example doing the same thing,
except that my vectors aren't as clean and easy as these.

This does not work. The loop does not iterate at all!

Using ...

```
for(vec3 Stepper; Stepper==Stepper; Stepper += StepValue)
```

... iterates through the loop either until the driver crashes,
or until the loop terminates itself manually.

The operaters `>`,`<`,`>=` and `<=` aren't allowed for vectors
and `lessThan` / `greaterThan`  neither.

So how do I work with this, besides running infinite loops?

Is there any other option besides using `==` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (vec3 Stepper = Origin; all(lessThan(Stepper, Destination)); Stepper += StepValue)
```

**lessThan**, **lessThanEqual** and the like return a bvec* that can be evaluated to a boolean value using the functions **all** and **any**. However, be aware that this will still not iterate in your example, since x and z of your destination are 0 and thus not >= Stepper.

Comment: Oh wow I got a response! Thank you so much, I'll experiment with this soon! :D